# Replacing repeated second character in column and displacing the one remaining. - python

Tags: python

Im working with a Dataframe which has two types of input errors (miss-placed period) in a column. Values should be numeric which is why it should only have one period, and based on reality the value's range is between 0 and 2. I'm thinking on replacing one of the dots for an empty character and move the one remaining in order for the value to be within the expected range.
Yet I don't know how. I would appreciate your help.

Small example of what I have:

1     11.90.11
2     12.9110
3     12.8.117
4     13.093
5     131.32

Should be:

1     1.19011
2     1.29110
3     1.28117
4     1.3093
5     1.3132

Comment: Hello. With a reproducible example, we'll be able to better understand your issue--what you've tried, what didn't work, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: In what format are you handling the data? Are you reading it in? Do you already have it as a list? These are important to include in the question.

Comment: Range between 0 and 2 is inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Range between 0 and 2 is inclusive

Comment: @Kraigolas I'm working on a Dataframe. These values are a specific column of the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant but does the trick assuming you're working in a dataframe:

```
df['new_field'] = (df['field'].str.strip('.').str[:1] + '.' + df['field'].str.strip('.').str[1:])
```

Strip the column's values of "." then add "." back in at the 1st position.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function `fix_val` for you. As input it takes a string and the output is a string too.

Your explenation is a bit unclear, so you might have to adapt my function.
My Idea: i seperate the first digit from the rest, delete all the points and set them together. It doesn't include math, only chars handling.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
def fix_val(val):
    splits=val[1:].split(".")
    string=val[0]+"."+"".join(splits)
    return string

def main(args):
    l=["11.90.11", "12.9110", "12.8.117", "13.093", "131.32"]
    for val in l:
        print(fix_val(val))
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```